# Android Studio how to split up a string to display serial data in two different forms?

Tags: android, string, split, uart

I am being sent capacitance readings and temperature sensor readings over bluetooth using UART.

I am attempting to do this by editing a pre existing [open source app called nRF-UART](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/Android-nRF-UART).

I am trying to display the temperature data on a live updating static text view, and display the capacitance data as a vertical progress bar to show the level of water being measured. In order to do that I think I need the capacitance data to be on a **separate string** from the temperature data.

Here is where the string is being printed out at:

```
   if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {

                 final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         try {
                            String text = new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
                                listAdapter.add(text);
                                messageListView.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter.getCount()-1);


                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
```

How can I split up the values and bring them outside of `listAdapter'?

The string will look like this

```
1,75,460,0
```

Where 75 is the temperature in Fahrenheit, and 460 is the capacitance reading in mL. 1 is just a starting bit, and 0 is the ending bit.

Comment: Add an example of the string value that you receive from the UART reading.

Comment: I don't have a screenshot, I can get one tomorrow. But it will be like this

    1, 75, 470, 0

Comment: For splitting the string you should refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481842/7436540

Comment: @LucasDeMoraisCabrales , thank you! Now can I just put the progress bar code 
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+10);

and the textview code 

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
                             TextView.setText(part1);

in the same function?